# Rest API plugin wordpress disable default routes

Tags: wordpress, api

Hello guy's Please help me i install REST API plugin WP and i adding some specific route and any things it's work fine as i wont. But I want to disable default route exemple : 
/wp-json/
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this on your plugin for remove all default route.

```
remove_action( 'rest_api_init', 'create_initial_rest_routes', 0 );
```

Answer (score 12):

As of Wordpress 4.7 it seems to be the following (noting 99 instead of 0):

```
remove_action('rest_api_init', 'create_initial_rest_routes', 99);
```

However this will also remove any custom content type routes. So instead you may choose to use:

```
add_filter('rest_endpoints', function($endpoints) {

    unset( $endpoints['/wp/v2/users'] );
    // etc

    return $endpoints;
});
```

Comment: there is any cleaner way to do this ?

Comment: ....to? To do what exactly? To remove the default api routes, you can't really beat the one liner above. It's using `actions` and `filters` which is a pretty clean and abstract way to tackle modifications to core functionality

Comment: I mean your second opinion, because when I remove the `rest_api_init` then it clears custom routes as well(as you describe also). Basically I need to disable the default routes and add custom routes.

Comment: are we need to unset all the default routes one by one ? are we having any cleaner solution for that ? to be precise : I asked new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42757726/disable-default-routes-of-wp-rest-api