# Disable default routes of WP REST API

Tags: wordpress, rest, routes, wp-api

I need to disable default routes of `WP REST API` and add custom routes.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816170/rest-api-plugin-wordpress-disable-default-routes) which helps me to find following answer.

> ```
> remove_action('rest_api_init', 'create_initial_rest_routes', 99);
> ```
>
> However this will also remove any custom content type routes. So
>   instead you may choose to use:
>
> ```
> add_filter('rest_endpoints', function($endpoints) {
>     if ( isset( $endpoints['/wp/v2/users'] ) ) {
>         unset( $endpoints['/wp/v2/users'] );
>     }
>     // etc
> });
> ```

But from that way I need to know all the default routes and remove one by one which is not a cleanest way to do.

I would like to know whether there is any cleaner way to achieve that ?

**UPDATE 1 :**

As per the Chris's suggestion I would add more details to question.

Currently I am using `rest_api_init` filter to add my custom routes by using `register_rest_route` method as per the below code which I found on [this article](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/).

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v1', '/sample/', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
  ) );
} );

function my_awesome_func( $data ) {
  return 'somthing';
}
```

The custom route works well, but unfortunately I can't disable the default routes such as `/wp/v2/posts`.

**My question :**

**How to unset/disable the default routes while using the `rest_api_init` filter to register new custom routes ?**

Comment: for future reference : Initial question was deviated bit with the UPDATE 1. the code on the initial question will not be working with `rest_api_init` filter. @Chris was answered to the initial question and then I changed it bit, So he will be awarded with bounty. BUT INCASE if SOMEONE LOOKING FOR AN ANSWER FOR `UPDATE 1`, PLEASE REFER MY OWN ANSWER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[REST API Toolbox](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api-toolbox/) did the job for me.

We can handle many things via that plugin.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't really answer your own question? You asked for a way to do it one by one - this plugin just disables all? Or am I missing something

Comment: When I added this question I thought the code you provided in other question will help to disable the default routes at least one by one. But when use `rest_api_init ` to create custom routes it doesn't work as I expected. But I didn't explain that on the question well. my bad. Actually I need to disable the default routes while using `rest_api_init ` . Hope I am clear enough now. But yes, I agree, that is not describe well enough in the question .

Comment: @Chris No I need to disable all

Comment: Ah ok, I misunderstood - the "one by one" line in your question threw me. I'm glad you found a solution to your answer though

Answer (score 11):

This question has already accepted answer. But if anybody find this useful.
We can easily remove default routes. Add following code in your theme's (child theme's if any) functions.php or in any custom plugin

```
add_filter('rest_endpoints', function( $endpoints ) {

    foreach( $endpoints as $route => $endpoint ){
        if( 0 === stripos( $route, '/wp/' ) ){
            unset( $endpoints[ $route ] );
        }
    }

    return $endpoints;
});
```

Comment: Very smart approach that avoids some problems with custom routes.

Answer (score 6):

As per the other question, this is the only "clean" way to do it currently. The cleanest way to approach things in Wordpress is by using filters and/or actions - this allows you to interact with core without making changes *in* core.

By tapping into filters/actions you are also giving *other* plugins the chance to operate on the filter/action arguments before/after your hook.

If you take a look at `class-wp-rest-server.php` you can easily look at all available filters and actions related to rest.

You will notice this one in particular:

```
    /**
     * Filters the array of available endpoints.
     *
     * @since 4.4.0
     *
     * @param array $endpoints The available endpoints. An array of matching regex patterns, each mapped
     *                         to an array of callbacks for the endpoint. These take the format
     *                         `'/path/regex' => array( $callback, $bitmask )` or
     *                         `'/path/regex' => array( array( $callback, $bitmask ).
     */
    $endpoints = apply_filters( 'rest_endpoints', $this->endpoints );
```

From my research, this is the very last spot to modify (remove, change or add) endpoints, and is the exact purpose of the filter.

As a sidenote, you don't need to do it "one by one" - you *could* just do `$endpoints = []` to start fresh.

Comment: Still I am confusing how & where to use `rest_endpoints` filter. Because I am already using `rest_api_init` filter to add my custom routes. But when ever I used `rest_endpoints` to clear the default routes, it clear up all including the custom once.

Comment: If you dump and die within the `rest_endpoints` filter, do you not see your own custom routes?

Comment: yes exactly. But I think I am using it on the wrong place or wrong way. I am pretty bad on wordpress.

Comment: BTW, I am using `register_rest_route` method to register custom routes

Comment: Perhaps post everything you have in your question (all the stuff related to rest) so people can help you better

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to disable member-only content from appearing in the REST API.  Instead of filtering the rest endpoints, I filtered the args used to register the post types:

```
function dbdb_unset_rest_routes( $args, $post_type ) {
    $allowed_post_types = array( 'page', 'post', 'company', 'job' );
    $allowed_post_types = apply_filters( 'dbdb_unset_rest_routes_types', $allowed_post_types );
    if( in_array( $post_type, $allowed_post_types ) ){
        return $args;
    } else {
         $args['show_in_rest'] = 0;
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'dbdb_unset_rest_routes', 20, 2 );
```

The REST API calls `get_post_types()` in `create_initial_rest_routes()` and looks for any post types that have `show_in_rest` set to `true`.  By filtering the args via the filter: `register_post_type_args` in `register_post_type()`, we can filter these routes from showing up in the API.